# notifications do not work on ios - flutter firebase messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been blocking notifications with flutter and firebase messaging for three days

Everything works correctly on android but on ios impossible to receive a notification I followed all the steps of the [firebase site](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration), but nothing to do I do not receive any notification on my phone.

someone would have an example code that works or a solution a functional tutorial, I tried everything I found on youtube and google but nothing works

Comment: Ok, but why are you "blocking" notifications?

Comment: have you registered firebase instance in app delegate and added p12 in firebase console by means are you sure you have implement all the stuff..